# Embed youtube cause js alert function fail

Tags: javascript, youtube, alert

I have embedded Youtube video in my website; however, it caused the first alert function fail.

The alert dialog will pop up and then immediately disappeared before I clicked confirm button.

This is the code:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bhxhNIQBKJI" 
   frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>alert("1");</script>
<script>alert("2");</script>
```

If I add second alert script, the first one fail, but the second work well. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Issue is known to happen only in Chrome [Issue here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2644)

Comment: Here your snippet works just fine, the alert shows as it should. Tested it on Chrome and Firefox. Can you add more information as it when its happening or what browser are you using? just for curiosity I created a jsfiddle and still I cannot reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ratempuj/

Comment: After I tested it, it only failed in Chrome.